# How to resolve code ERR_INVALID_URL in Angular-cli installation

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

In my windows-10, I installed:

nodejs-v16.13.0

npm -v8.1.0

When I tried to run npm install -g @angular/cli

I got this error:

> npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL

> npm ERR! Invalid URL

How do I get this resolve?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I just reconfigure proxy using this command:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Generally there is a log file associated with this message :

```
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-04T09_13_08_065Z-debug.log
```

You can see more details in this file.
I had the same problem, in my case I simply omitted the "http://" when I initially set up the proxy :

```
npm config set proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
             here !!! ^^^^^^^
```

For reference, it failed with this trace :

```
39 verbose stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
39 verbose stack     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
39 verbose stack     at onParseError (node:internal/url:552:9)
39 verbose stack     at new URL (node:internal/url:628:5)
39 verbose stack     at getProxyUri (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:147:53)
39 verbose stack     at getAgent (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:20:17)
39 verbose stack     at remoteFetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\remote.js:31:17)
39 verbose stack     at cacheFetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\cache\index.js:15:28)
39 verbose stack     at async fetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\fetch.js:82:7)
39 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1061:19)
39 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:930:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update npmrc file by adding `https_proxy=http://username:password@host:port`
Moreover, you may need also to add `strict-ssl=false`

Answer (score 0):

I just run all these commands

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
npm config --global rm proxy
npm config --global rm https-proxy
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

I am using tailwind so I just run

```
npm install 
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init
```

this work for me

Comment: Would it be possible to throw those commands into a command block so that it is easier to read (and copy paste)?
Also, and more importantly, please include a description of what the original problem is and why these commands solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem turn up recently.
I ran `npm config ls -l` and noticed that I had a badly formed setting for an npm repository that we use:

```
; "project" config from C:\MyPackage\.npmrc

@intercede-free:registry = "\"https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
```

Correcting the setting in the file that set the URL incorrectly fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this below command after removing the proxy and it worked

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```